# Android: Cannot cast from View to MapView

Tags: android, casting, android-mapview

I'm trying to run the Android MapView example, and am getting a 'Cannot cast from View to MapView' error in Eclipse.

My layout is as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/mainlayout"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<com.google.android.maps.MapView
    android:id="@+id/mapview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:apiKey="0jwi0saLYCPGfO-t7glg5bQoBz7jVKWCcgyQWQA"
 />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/zoomview"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@id/mapview"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

and the Activity code is

```
package org.gaz.mapapp;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ZoomControls;

import com.google.android.maps.*;

public class MapView extends MapActivity {

LinearLayout linearLayout;
MapView mapView;
ZoomControls mZoom;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstance) {
    linearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.mainlayout);
    mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);
    mZoom = (ZoomControls) mapView.getZoomControls();       
}

@Override
protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}
}
```

The error is caused by the line

```
mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);
```

Can anybody offer an suggestions as to a fix?

Cheers,
Gaz.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This probably stems from you naming your own class `MapView`. Try to specify the full class `com.google.android.maps.MapView` to distinguish it from your own `org.gaz.mapapp.MapView`.

Comment: I can't believe that I overlooked that! Thanks Frank!